# Excel VBA Sending emails with multiple attachements

Tags: vba, excel

So we are holding this big event and I have an excel sheet with everyones name, email address as well as their itinerary files (there are 2 of them) `Cells(x, 3)` and `Cells(x, 4)`. What I am trying to do is go down the column and send everyone a 'personalized' email with all of their information.

In the code, the `for` loop only goes to 3 because I am just testing it out by sending the emails to myself and don't want to end up getting 1000 emails :P

I keep getting a **Run-Time Error 440 (Automation Error)** at the lines where I attempt to add the attachments... not sure what's going on or how to remedy it any help is appreciated

**Code**

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties.

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim body, head, filePath, subject As String
    Dim x As Long
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Create e-mail item
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    filePath = "\\fileserver\homeshares\Tsee\My Documents\Metropolitan Sales\MNF"
    subject = "Important Travel Information for MNF Event this weekend"

    x = 1

    For x = 1 To 3
        head = "<HTML><BODY><P>Hi " & Cells(x, 1).Value & ",</P>"
        body = body & "<BR /><P>We are looking forward to having you at our <STRONG>Metropolitan Night Football Event</STRONG> this upcoming Sunday, <STRONG>11/17</STRONG>!  Note, that the Giants game time has changed from 8:30 PM to 4:25 PM.</P>"
        body = body & "<BR /><P>Please find attached your travel information packet that contains important addresses and confirmation numbers.  Please read through it and let me know if you have any questions.</P>"
        body = body & "<BR /><P>If you need to reach me this weekend, please call my cell phone <STRONG>(631) 793-9047</STRONG> or email me.</P>"
        body = body & "<BR /><P>Thanks,<BR />Liz</P></BODY></HTML>"

        With objMail
            .subject = subject
            .To = Cells(x, 2).Value
            .Attachments.Add = filePath & "/" & Cells(x, 3).Value
            .Attachments.Add = filePath & "/" & Cells(x, 4).Value
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = head & body
            .Send
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this a method call requiring a parameter, not an assignment. So instead of x = y, its x(y): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx

Comment: @bamie9l Awesome! That worked, but now at the `.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` line I get **Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument**

Comment: Declare this at the top of your code `Const olFormatHTML = 2` or replace `.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` by `.BodyFormat = 2`

Comment: @SiddharthRout So that works, but now I get a crazy automation error... it goes through the loop once.. sends 1 email and then when it gets up to `.subject = subject` I get **Run-time error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': Automation Error** which as far as I know is the same as **Run-Time Error 440**

Comment: Debug that line and see what is the value of `subject` at the time of error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout edit... sorry misread... how can I see the value at that time?

Comment: do you know how to step through the code using `F8`?

Comment: yes, thats how I figure out it was that line

Comment: no wait.. I know what the error is :) Posting an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Further to the above comments, @bamie9l has already solved one problem of yours

**Problem 2**

> @bamie9l Awesome! That worked, but now at the .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML line I get Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument – metsales 13 mins ago

You are latebinding with Outlook from Excel and `olFormatHTML` is an Outlook constant and hence Excel is unable to recognize it. In the `Immediate Window` of MS-Outlook if you type `?olFormatHTML` then you will note that the value of that constant is `2`

[image]

Hence we have to declare that constant in Excel. Like I mentioned, either you can put `Const olFormatHTML = 2` at the top of the code or replace `.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` by `.BodyFormat = 2`

**Problem 3**

> @SiddharthRout So that works, but now I get a crazy automation error... it goes through the loop once.. sends 1 email and then when it gets up to .subject = subject I get Run-time error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': Automation Error which as far as I know is the same as Run-Time Error 440 – metsales

The problem is that you are creating the outlook item outside the loop by

```
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Outlook already sent that email and now for the next email you will have to re-create it. So move that line inside the loop.

```
For x = 1 To 3
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    head = "<HTML><BODY><P>Hi " & Cells(x, 1).Value & ",</P>"
    Body = "Blah Blah"

    With objMail

        .subject = subject
        .To = Cells(x, 2).Value
        .Attachments.Add = FilePath & "/" & Cells(x, 3).Value
        .Attachments.Add = FilePath & "/" & Cells(x, 4).Value
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = head & Body
        .Send
    End With
Next x
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks so much! can't believe I didn't think of that before. Now that you say that, it makes complete sense. In essence I was trying to send a sent email (an email that no longer exists) over and over again...